# How to disable button on click and then call the click event after that

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a button that is executing some insertion into the database.

Problem is when user fills the form and click on the buttons more than one time insertion process executed multiple times.

So i disabled the button on "OnClientClick" of button using script but it does not execute the server side Click event.

here is my button :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" Text="Continue To Application >>" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" ValidationGroup="criteria" OnClientClick="DiableButton(this)"></asp:Button>
```

function that disables the button

```
function DiableButton(btn) {   

    $(btn).attr("disabled", "disabled");        
    $("[Id$='hfDisableBtn']").val($(btn).attr("id"));      

}
```

function that enables the function that is called from the server side after executing insertion

```
function EnableButton() {
   var btn = $("[Id$='hfDisableBtn']").val();
   $(btn).removeAttr("disabled");
   $("[Id$='hfDisableBtn']").val("");    
}
```

what i want is

```
1) first disable button on click if all the validation satisfied (like Require filed validator)
2) then call the server side click event of that same button
3) enable that button after executing server side click event
```

How can i achieve this ???

Please help me 
Thanks is advance

Comment: show the validation...after validation you can trigger the button attribute change.

Comment: I have used asp.net validation like "RequiredFieldValidator" and "RegularExpressionValidator",  you can see that in my button as i have used ValidationGroup="criteria"

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by replacing your asp:Button with the html button and on that button click create an AJAX call to your server function (needs to be marked as WebMethod) then you can exactly follow your requirements

```
1) first disable button on click if all the validation satisfied (like Require filed validator)
2) then call the server side click event of that same button
3) enable that button after executing server side click event
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your JS code works as you expect, but if the functions work then it should too

```
1) first disable button on click if all the validation satisfied (like Require filed validator)
2) then call the server side click event of that same button
```

You said that the function works but doesn't fire the server function so here you only have to add the `return true;` in your  JS function and the server function will be called

```
3) enable that button after executing server side click event
```

In your server side function add this line to call the JS function

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Funct", "EnableButton();", true);
```

Also, if you are storing the ID of the button to exclusively use it in these two functions, you can leave them like this:

```
function DiableButton(btn) {   
    $(btn).attr("disabled", "disabled");             
    return true;
}

function EnableButton() {
   var btn = $('#<%=btnContinue.ClientID %>').val();
   $(btn).removeAttr("disabled");  
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The required field validator does its work before call the server, and even before trigger the onclientclick function, so you don't have to be worried about

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $('#btnContinue').prop('disabled', false); 
 $('#btnContinue').click();
 $('#btnContinue').prop('disabled', true);
```